# Things to be aware of when using voronoi shaped traces

Tags: pcb, routing, trace

I was thinking of giving voronoi shaped traces (e.g. http://publications.csail.mit.edu/abstracts/abstracts05/rus/rus.html for those who need an example, or just google image search it) a try.

In general is there something I should be aware of, compared to traditional (more or less) autorouted traces, that could fail or needs special care of or could fail to work as desired?

Comment: eh, if you're just playing around with some two layer low speed circuits then I don't see why it would be a problem.  Going to be annoying to solder those pins on the traces with the large copper floods.   I'd consider adding thermal relief if possible.

Comment: Any tight angles could become etchant traps if the boards are going to be etched. This seems like something to shy away from if you're not rapid prototyping on milled boards, even then questionable.

Comment: Beware of excess capacitance in certain cases (crystal oscillators, for example). Also, the width of the cut determines your isolation, so make it wider in high-voltage circuits.

Comment: @MattYoung: It is solely for proto milling and hopefully a speedup there.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is, your PCB is going to change a lot from prototype to production, therefore negligible time savings. Why bother?

Comment: Lots of chances for shorts (especially with no solder mask) and lots of added capacitance (minimum clearances everywhere), but in general there is nothing inherently wrong with it. If you end up with a huge chunk of copper connected to a sensitive analog node (perhaps coupled to a nearby node or to a housing etc.) you may be sorry, but that can happen with any kind of sloppy layout.

Comment: @MattYoung: Mostly I am curious, and they look somewhat unique that way. This is also why I asked this question, if it means problems popping out everywhere then its likely not a good idea to even try, other than for one time hobby projects.

Comment: The time saved by a shorter routing path will be consumed by the additional time spent drawing in all the voronoi shaped traces. Also, the EDA tools may have an issue with these, so you may need to spend some time configuring your design rules appropriately. All that being said, this approach could be great for power PCBAs where the additional copper can help with heat dissipation.

Comment: @FixItUntilIt'sBroken: It seems there are some programs available that take a conventionally routed pcb and extend the traces to their voronoi equivalents.

Comment: The people at http://reprap.org/wiki/PCB_Milling have a lot of success with Voronoi-shaped PCB traces.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some reasons that I came up with (as well as compiling reasons identified in the comments):

- Your capacitance will be a bit more (especially if you have a ground plane on the other side). You can see a lot more coupling between two nodes that would normally not interact significantly. (David Tweed, Spehro Pefhany)
- If you're migrating from a prototype board to a professionally fabbed board, you might miss any trace under-sizing issues in the design as all traces will be wider than drawn.
- If you're migrating from a prototype to a fabbed board, your layout differences will reduce your confidence in the prototype testing. (Matt Young)
- Drills can not be visually aligned (or visually verified) as it is not clear where in the shape the drill should have been.
- Pad to pad isolation for SMT parts may be painful to enforce, and may cause problems in parts with thermal pads.
- No ability to add thermal reliefs to pins (that I can tell).
- Wider copper pours will make soldering more difficult. (Some Hardware Guy)
- It obliterates text and annotations in copper layers.
- Any separation intended for voltage isolation would cause issues unless a larger isolation bit was used. (Dave Tweed)

  It probably depends on how big of a board you're making and how slow your milling machine is. If it's really slow, and a big board, then you could probably justify using Voroni shapes for prototyping. For a board that maybe takes 1-2 hours, I probably wouldn't bother with the risk.